# @DisabledIfSystemProperty() not working on afterEach or afterAll hook

Tags: conditional-statements, junit5

Perhaps I've misunderstood where the conditional annotations can be used, but I am attempting to run an afterEach hook, or an afterAll hook only if a system property is passed in.

For example:

`mvn test -DrunTearDownScript=false`

and for my afterEach hook:

```
@AfterAll
@DisabledIfSystemProperty(named = "runTearDownScript", matches = "false")
void clearDownTestEnvironment() {
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("runTearDownScript"));
}
```

In the above example, I'd expect the `println` to not be printed, but it is "false".

I guess I can write my own condition inside the hook, but ideally the use of annotations look cleaner.

Any help would be hugely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Perhaps I've misunderstood where the conditional annotations can be used...

Yes. They can only be used on "a container or (a) test (method)".

Copied from https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-conditional-execution

> The ExecutionCondition extension API in JUnit Jupiter allows developers to either enable or disable **a container or test** based on certain conditions programmatically.
>
> [...]
>
> Each of the conditional annotations listed in the following sections can only be declared once on a given **test interface, test class, or test method**.
>
> [...]
>
> **2.7.3** System Property Conditions
>
> **A container or test** may be enabled or disabled based on the value of the named JVM system property via the @EnabledIfSystemProperty and @DisabledIfSystemProperty annotations. The value supplied via the matches attribute will be interpreted as a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you. I thought just as much.

I guess I'll write my own assumption within the hook.